# How are dynamic arrays implemented in C++?

Tags: c++

While creating an array, the compiler has to know the size of it? For example, the following code snippet does not compile.

```
class A
{
   int n;
   int arr[n];
};
```

But, the following compiles.

```
int main()
{
  int n;

  std::cin >> n;
  int arr[n];
}
```

Why?

Comment: the later one is extension, it is not in standard

Comment: Technically, the second is illegal within C++.  Definitely either an exception of the compiler, or an uncaught error!!!

Comment: @Soumya Why `;` at the end of main function ? Use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: The statement `sin>>n;` is actually a *sin* in C++. It will not compile.

Comment: @Nawaz did you make the same error? I always believed it was `std::cin`

Comment: @josefx, And went on to say it won't compile.

Comment: @chris my error, I misunderstood the 'is actually a' part of his sentence.

Comment: @josefx: The italicized 'sin' in my statement is used to mean 'illegal'. Now read the statement again replacing *sin* with *illegal*, you will understand it.

Comment: @Nawaz now that is a pretty bad use for the word sin, after all sin != illegal (which is why my brain refuses to parse it that way and I end up with cmath std::sin - which isn't any better).

Comment: @josefx: You still didn't get why I used *sin* in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

Standard C++ does not support variable-length arrays.<sup>1</sup>

If you want this behaviour, I would suggest using a `std::vector` rather than a raw C-style array.

---

<sub>1. However, you can find them in C99, or in non-standard language extensions.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

(1) 
The first thing that happens when you create an instance of A is allocating the memory, at that point the member `n` does not exist so it is impossible to know how much memory `arr` needs.

(2) Creates an array on the stack, this only moves the stackpointer a bit.

Comment: +1 for the only post that actually answers the question that was asked.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create an array of variable size you must do it on the heap using `new`. The only way that you can use it the way you have would be if you had declared your integer as a constant.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment of compilation the value of variable n is unknown (it's just what've been in memory under the address it was given), so you can't make a variable of unknown size.
and in second case, you know the size, as you've used cin (not sin).